# ios storyboard remove hidden constraints

Tags: ios, storyboard, constraints, size-classes

Once i added contraint to view , than i thought its wrong constraint so i tried to
delete constraint and add it again but its not removed its their in form of hidden state.

[image: snapshot]

how do i remove them.

only way to remove them is to remove the whole view and add it again..

please note clear constraint from these [image: option1]

and [image: option2]

is not working to remove constraints.

Select Edit and press delete from keyboard also wouldnt work [image: see]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be a menu on the left that displays all the constraints. If it's not there, there is a button on the bottom-left to show it:

[image: button screenshot]

Then you can just find the constraint and delete (backspace) it:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Select the **Edit** button you shown in your first image then press delete button in your keyboard.